# Removing duplicate keys from python dictionary but summing the values

Tags: python, duplicates

I have a dictionary in python

```
d = {tags[0]: value, tags[1]: value, tags[2]: value, tags[3]: value, tags[4]: value}
```

imagine that this dict is 10 times bigger, it has 50 keys and 50 values. Duplicates can be found in this tags but even then values are essential. How can I simply trimm  it to recive new dict without duplicates of keys but with summ of values instead?

`d = {'cat': 5, 'dog': 9, 'cat': 4, 'parrot': 6, 'cat': 6}`

result

`d = {'cat': 15, 'dog': 9, 'parrot': 6}`

Comment: You do not have that dictionary, all keys are unique.

Comment: You can't have duplicates in a python dictionary

Comment: You should consider changing the Question name as dictionaries cannot have duplicate keys in the first place

Answer (score 7):

I'd like to improve Paul Seeb's answer:

```
tps = [('cat',5),('dog',9),('cat',4),('parrot',6),('cat',6)]
result = {}
for k, v in tps:
  result[k] = result.get(k, 0) + v
```

Comment: This is excellent actually. What I was thinking but couldn't figure out :)

Comment: track = []
for key, value in neop1:
 track.append(key)
 result[key] = ( result.get(key,0) + float(value) ) / track.count(key)      #this would get you the average

Answer (score 6):

```
tps = [('cat',5),('dog',9),('cat',4),('parrot',6),('cat',6)]

from collections import defaultdict

dicto = defaultdict(int)

for k,v in tps:
    dicto[k] += v
```

Result:

```
>>> dicto
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'dog': 9, 'parrot': 6, 'cat': 15})
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of just doing dict of those things (can't have multiples of same key in a dict) I assume you can have them in a list of tuple pairs. Then it is just as easy as

```
tps = [('cat',5),('dog',9),('cat',4),('parrot',6),('cat',6)]
result = {}
for k,v in tps:
    try:
        result[k] += v
    except KeyError:
        result[k] = v

>>> result
{'dog': 9, 'parrot': 6, 'cat': 15}
```

changed mine to more explicit try-except handling. Alfe's is very concise though

Comment: Why not use `collections.defaultdict` ?

Comment: Why would you though? I feel that making the import for something as simple as this is over complicating the solution. Alfe's answer is the obvious choice here. Mine does the same as his its just more explicit in meaning

Comment: Just a matter of taste, I guess. I would use `defaultdict` though. I prefer the readability of it. Also it is designed to handle cases like that.

Comment: @PaulSeeb Thank you for the merits but actually in any decently large project I'm using `defaultdict` anyway for some task, so the import will happen anyway.  Using it instead of my solution has several advantages.  One thing: consider a complex `k` like `(n+5) / len(x)`.  In my solution it would be `result[(n+5) / len(x)] = result.get((n+5) / len(x), 0) + v` thus doubling the code for `k`.  Introducing a local variable could fix this, but `d[k] = d.get(k, 0) + v` might still do a double lookup in the dict.  A simple `d[k] += v` is cleaner and clearer, so in real code I'd prefer `defaultdict`.

Answer (score 2):

This the perfect situation for using a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) data structure.
Let's take a look at what it does on few familiar data structures:

```py
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> list_a = ["A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "A", "D"]
>>> list_b = ["B", "A", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D"]
>>> c1 = Counter(list_a)
>>> c2 = Counter(list_b)
>>> c1
Counter({'A': 3, 'C': 2, 'B': 1, 'D': 1})
>>> c2
Counter({'C': 3, 'B': 2, 'A': 1, 'D': 1})
>>> c1 - c2
Counter({'A': 2})
>>> c1 + c2
Counter({'C': 5, 'A': 4, 'B': 3, 'D': 2})
>>> c_diff = c1 - c2
>>> c_diff.update([77, 77, -99, 0, 0, 0])
>>> c_diff
Counter({0: 3, 'A': 2, 77: 2, -99: 1})
```

As you can see this behaves as a `set` that keeps the count of element occurrences as a value.
However, the dictionary in itself is a set-like structure where for values we don't have to have numbers, so the things get more interesting:

```py
>>> dic1 = {"A":"a", "B":"b"}
>>> cd = Counter(dic1)
>>> cd
Counter({'B': 'b', 'A': 'a'})
>>> cd.update(B='bB123')
>>> cd
Counter({'B': 'bbB123', 'A': 'a'})


>>> dic2 = {"A":[1,2], "B": ("a", 5)}
>>> cd2 = Counter(dic2)
>>> cd2
Counter({'B': ('a', 5), 'A': [1, 2]})
>>> cd2.update(A=[42], B=(2,2))
>>> cd2
Counter({'B': ('a', 5, 2, 2), 'A': [1, 2, 42, 42, 42, 42]})
>>> cd2 = Counter(dic2)
>>> cd2
Counter({'B': ('a', 5), 'A': [1, 2]})
>>> cd2.update(A=[42], B=("new elem",))
>>> cd2
Counter({'B': ('a', 5, 'new elem'), 'A': [1, 2, 42]})
```

As we can see the value we are adding/changing has to be of the same type in `update` or it throws `TypeError`.

For the situation we have in the question, we can just go with the flow

```py
>>> d = {'cat': 5, 'dog': 9, 'cat': 4, 'parrot': 6, 'cat': 6}
>>> cd3 = Counter(d)
>>> cd3
Counter({'dog': 9, 'parrot': 6, 'cat': 6})
>>> cd3.update(parrot=123)
>>> cd3
Counter({'parrot': 129, 'dog': 9, 'cat': 6})
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhapse what you really want is a [`tuple`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) of key-value pairs.

```
[('dog',1), ('cat',2), ('cat',3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but the Counter class might be helpful for what you're trying to do:
http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Answer (score 0):

This option serves but is done with a list, or best can provide insight

```
data = []
        for i, j in query.iteritems():
            data.append(int(j))    
        try:
            data.sort()
        except TypeError:
            del data
        data_array = []
        for x in data:
            if x not in data_array:
                data_array.append(x)  
        return data_array
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question that you want to get rid of duplicate key data, use update function of dictionary while creating the dictionary. it will overwrite the data if the key is duplicate.

```
tps = [('cat',5),('dog',9),('cat',4),('parrot',6),('cat',6)]
result = {}
for k, v in tps:
    result.update({k:v})
for k in result:
    print "%s: %s" % (k, result[k])
```

Output will look like:
**dog: 9
parrot: 6
cat: 6**