# Concatenate strings by groups python

Tags: python, string, group-by, string-concatenation

I would like to concatenate a list of strings into new strings grouped over values in a list. Here is an example of what I mean:

**Input**

```
key = ['1','2','2','3']
data = ['a','b','c','d']
```

**Result**

```
newkey = ['1','2','3']
newdata = ['a','b c','d']
```

I understand how to join text. But I don't know how to iterate correctly over the values of the list to aggregate the strings that are common to the same key value.

Any help or suggestions appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in zip(key, data):
    d[k].append(v)

print [(k, ' '.join(v)) for k, v in d.items()]
```

Output:

```
[('1', 'a'), ('3', 'd'), ('2', 'b c')]
```

And how to get new lists:

```
newkey, newvalue = d.keys(), [' '.join(v) for v in d.values()]
```

And with saved order:

```
newkey, newvalue = zip(*[(k, ' '.join(d.pop(k))) for k in key if k in d])
```

Comment: Well played! I was over-thinking this, really.

Comment: And how do you get from your output to the desired output?

Comment: This is better than `groupby` because it doesn't require `keys` to be sorted.

Comment: @defuz: You could have used `zip(*[(k, ' '.join(v)) for k, v in d.items()])` too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I also saved ordering for you ;)

Comment: @defuz: Perfect! I do wonder what approach is going to be the best performer though (including and excluding having to sort first for the `itertools.groupby()` version).

Answer (score 2):

Use the `itertools.groupby()` function to combine elements; zip will let you group two input lists into two output lists:

```
import itertools
import operator

newkey, newdata = [], []
for key, items in itertools.groupby(zip(key, data), key=operator.itemgetter(0)):
    # key is the grouped key, items an iterable of key, data pairs
    newkey.append(key)
    newdata.append(' '.join(d for k, d in items))
```

You can turn this into a list comprehension with a bit more `zip()` magic:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

newkey, newdata = zip(*[(k, ' '.join(d for _, d in it)) for k, it in groupby(zip(key, data), key=itemgetter(0))])
```

Note that this does require the input to be sorted; `groupby` only groups elements based on the consecutive keys being the same. On the other hand, it does preserve that initial sorted order.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `itertools.groupby()` on `zip(key,data)`:

```
In [128]: from itertools import *

In [129]: from operator import *

In [133]: lis=[(k," ".join(x[1] for x in g)) for k,g in groupby(zip(key,data),key=itemgetter(0))]

In [134]: newkey,newdata=zip(*lis)

In [135]: newkey
Out[135]: ('1', '2', '3')

In [136]: newdata
Out[136]: ('a', 'b c', 'd')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont feel like importing collections you can always use a regular dictionary.

```
key = ['1','2','2','3']
data = ['a','b','c','d']
newkeydata = {}

for k,d in zip(key,data):
    newkeydata[k] = newkeydata.get(k, []).append(d)
```

Comment: but ... why ... ???  If memory serves, you could also use `newkeydata.setdefault(k,[]).append(d)`, but a defaultdict is much cleaner.

Comment: Your missing for k,d in zip(key,data):<---

Comment: Had this argument before here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654499/removing-duplicate-keys-from-python-dictionary-but-summing-the-values/10654567#10654567

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of variety, here is a solution that works without any external libraries and without dictionaries:

```
def group_vals(keys, vals):
    new_keys= sorted(set(keys))
    zipped_keys = zip(keys, keys[1:]+[''])
    zipped_vals = zip(vals, vals[1:]+[''])
    new_vals = []
    for i, (key1, key2) in enumerate(zipped_keys):
        if key1 == key2:
            new_vals.append(' '.join(zipped_vals[i]))
        else:
            new_vals.append(zipped_vals[i][0])
    return new_keys, new_vals

group_vals([1,2,2,3], ['a','b','c','d'])
# --> ([1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b c', 'd'])
```

But I know that it's quite ugly and probably not as performant as the other solutions. Just for demonstration purposes. :)