# Python: Collections.Counter vs defaultdict(int)

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose I have some data that looks like the following.

```
Lucy = 1
Bob = 5
Jim = 40
Susan = 6
Lucy = 2
Bob = 30
Harold = 6
```

I want to combine:

1. remove duplicate keys, and
2. add the values for these duplicate keys.

That means I'd get the key/values:

```
Lucy = 3
Bob = 35
Jim = 40
Susan = 6
Harold = 6
```

Would it be better to use (from collections) a counter or a default dict for this?

Comment: Do both work? Then flip a coin. That said, it seems that `collections.Counter` is there to tally a list with repeating elements.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Both `Counter` and `defaultdict(int)` can work fine here, but there are few differences between them:

- `Counter` supports most of the operations you can do on a [multiset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset). So, if you want to use those operation then go for Counter.
- `Counter` won't add new keys to the dict when you query for missing keys. So, if your queries include keys that may not be present in the dict then better use `Counter`.

Example:

```
>>> c = Counter()
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> c[0], d[1]
(0, 0)
>>> c
Counter()
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {1: 0})
```

Example:

- `Counter` also has a method called `most_common` that allows you to sort items by their count. To get the same thing in `defaultdict` you'll have to use `sorted`.

Example:

```
>>> c = Counter('aaaaaaaaabbbbbbbcc')
>>> c.most_common()
[('a', 9), ('b', 7), ('c', 2)]
>>> c.most_common(2)          #return 2 most common items and their counts
[('a', 9), ('b', 7)]
```

- `Counter` also allows you to create a list of elements from the Counter object.

Example:

```
>>> c = Counter({'a':5, 'b':3})
>>> list(c.elements())
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b']
```

So, depending on what you want to do with the resulting dict you can choose between `Counter` and `defaultdict(int)`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Found another good question here --http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654499/removing-duplicate-keys-from-python-dictionary-but-summing-the-values

Comment: I think you meant `defaultdict` in the second bullet, when you talk about missing keys.

Comment: @dmvianna no, the second bullet is correct as written.

Answer (score 5):

`defaultdict(int)` seems to work more faster.

```
In [1]: from collections import Counter, defaultdict

In [2]: def test_counter():
   ...:     c = Counter()
   ...:     for i in range(10000):
   ...:         c[i] += 1
   ...:

In [3]: def test_defaultdict():
   ...:     d = defaultdict(int)
   ...:     for i in range(10000):
   ...:         d[i] += 1
   ...:

In [4]: %timeit test_counter()
5.28 ms ± 1.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [5]: %timeit test_defaultdict()
2.31 ms ± 68.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: As of Python 3.2 that may not hold, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27801945/surprising-results-with-python-timeit-counter-vs-defaultdict-vs-dict?lq=1

Comment: @TalJerome I tested this in Python 3.6.

Comment: Why not pass `range()` object directly to `Counter()`?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary because it was intended to simulate adding 10000 values separately from different sources than a single iterable.

Answer (score 3):

I support using `defaultdict(int)` for summing counts, such as in this case, and `Counter()` for counting list elements. In your case, the following would be the cleanest solution:

```
name_count = [
    ("Lucy", 1),
    ("Bob", 5),
    ("Jim", 40),
    ("Susan", 6),
    ("Lucy", 2),
    ("Bob", 30),
    ("Harold", 6)
]

aggregate_counts = defaultdict(int)
for name, count in name_count:
    aggregate_counts[name] += count
```