# Python add numbers in a list

Tags: python, list, count, addition

Anyone can help me with these?
Basically I have list begin created as shown below:

```
>>> item
[('apple', 7, 'population'), ('apple', 9, 'population'), ('apple', 3, 'disease'), ('orange', 6, 'population')]
```

I want to combine the result of the object only when such as apple and population is met. This is my end result that I want:

```
>>> item
[('apple', 16, 'population'), ('apple', 3, 'disease'), ('orange', 6, 'population')]
```

Any help will be appreciated.

My fault if the question wasn't clear: This is some of my code.

```
def add(par):
    temp_dict = {}
    for name, count, term in par:
            if name in temp_dict:
                    temp_dict[name] += count
            else:
                    temp_dict[name] = count
    result = []
    for name, count, term in par:
            if name in temp_dict:
                    result.append((name, temp_dict[name], term)) 
                    del temp_dict[name]
    return result
```

How can I make ammendment to the class so that, it returns the desired result?
The code above still adds the "apple" together, which is this:

> > > item
> > >           [('apple', 19, 'disease'), ('orange', 6, 'population')]

Comment: Can you post some code for what you have already tried?

Comment: Use `(name, term)` as key instead of just `name`.

Comment: @Aleph My bad if my question wasn't clear for the community. How can I edit from the method def add(par)?

Comment: instead of explicit test whether a key already exists in the dict you may either use `collections.defaultdict`, as shown in my answer, or do `my_dict[new_key] = my_dict.setdefault[new_key, 0] + new_value`

Comment: @bgbg thanks btw. I have learned a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may achieve the desired result as follows:

```
In [6]: my_items = [('apple', 7, 'population'), ('apple', 9, 'population'), ('apple', 3, 'disease'), ('orange', 6, 'population')]

In [7]: import collections

In [8]: my_counter = collections.defaultdict(int)

In [9]: for i in my_items:
    # at this point, i is a tuple, let's unpack it
    (fruit, n, category) = i
    # use the tuple (fruit, category) as a key.
    # note that this has to be a tuple, and not a list
    my_counter[(fruit, category)] += n
   ...:

In [10]: my_counter
Out[10]: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {('orange', 'population'): 6, ('apple', 'population'): 16, ('apple', 'disease'): 3})
```

(note that this is an [IPython](http://ipython.org/) session I highly recommend it over the vanilla shell for interactive work)

In this example, `my_counter` is a modified `dict` object. It differs from the "regular" `dict` by the fact that if the specified key isn't available, a default value will be automatically created (in our case -- integer zero).
From your example I understand that you are new to Python. If you need more  aggregation power for large data amounts, you may want to take a look at [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/).

Good luck.

**EDIT** For the sake of completeness, following [keimina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2931409/keimina)'s [answer in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24930626/17523), you might consider using `collections.Counter` that has many [features that are useful for counters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19883180/17523) such as `most_common()` function that was new for me.

Comment: Note that you can just do `for fruit, n, category in my_items:`

Comment: jonrsharpe: right. for some reason I tend to do unpacking in a separate line. go figure

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `collections.Counter`. It's useful when you count something.

```
from collections import  Counter
item = [('apple', 7, 'population'), ('apple', 9, 'population'), ('apple', 3, 'disease'), ('orange', 6, 'population')]

c = Counter()
for name, count, term in item:
    c += Counter({(name, term):count})

print [(name, count, term) for (name, term), count in dict(c).items()]
#[('apple', 16, 'population'), ('apple', 3, 'disease'), ('orange', 6, 'population')]
```