# How to find duplicate letters in Python using Hashtables

Tags: python, duplicates, hashtable

I was wondering how would you get the number of duplicate letters in a string and store the information into a hashtable? As in this order: {(DUPLICATE LETTER HERE) : (NUMBER OF DUPLICATES FOR THAT LETTER HERE)}
I have been having a lot of trouble with getting an answer and am looking for code for this specific function.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you allowed to use dictionaries?

Comment: As long as the information is in a {Value : Key} format, dictionaries would work as well.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40950905/find-count-of-characters-within-the-string-in-python or similar.

Comment: This link **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40950905/find-count-of-characters-within-the-string-in-python)** helps. Basically, use Collections.