# Idiomatic, Linear-time, Dictionary of Counts in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, idioms

I have some list:

```
list =  ["apple", "orange", "orange", "apple", "grape"]
```

I want to turn this into a dictionary where the key is the fruit, and the value is the number of times it occurs in the list.
The list could be rather large, so it would be good for it to be linear time.

This is rather easy to do in a verbose way:

```
from collections import DefaultDict
dict_of_counts = DefaultDict(int)
for item in list:
    dict_of_counts[item] += 1
```

This is clearly O(n) time, but it feels like I should be able to do it via a dictionary comprehension.
The only things I can think of though involve multiple calls to `len` or `count`, so it would be O(kn) time (where k is the distinct number of keys in my list).

Can someone point to a more "pythonic" way to do this (which I'd imagine involves the comprehension), or should I keep the above, verbose, implementation?

Comment: `from collections import Counter;c = Counter(my_list)`?

Comment: Don't name lists `list`

Comment: @user3483203 I don't plan to, nor do my lists truly contain fruit.

Comment: Try using a [defaultdict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26731675/python-count-occurrences-in-a-list-using-dict-comprehension-generator)

Comment: @Miraj50 Why use that instead of `Counter`?

Comment: @U9-Forward Check out the link. The answer is there most probably. Its faster, I guess.

Comment: @Miraj50 Yeah, not always, Btw it's not efficient at all, and the ashwini doesn't recommend this at all, says "(not recommended at all :-))"

Comment: @U9-Forward I believe, you didn't read the whole answer. Jump to the `defauldict` part.

Comment: @Miraj50 Do you mean by the `groupby` solution

Answer (score 1):

Use `Counter`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> l =  ["apple", "orange", "orange", "apple", "grape"]
>>> Counter(l)
Counter({'apple': 2, 'orange': 2, 'grape': 1})
>>>
```

And also easy to convert back:

```
>>> c=Counter(l)
>>> list(c.elements())
['apple', 'apple', 'orange', 'orange', 'grape']
>>>
```

And if want a dict:

```
>>> dict(c)
{'apple': 2, 'orange': 2, 'grape': 1}
>>>
```

BTW don't name variables any existing object (now `list`)

Or another way is:

```
>>> {i:l.count(i) for i in l}
{'apple': 2, 'orange': 2, 'grape': 1}
>>>
```

Comment: Is {i:l.count(i) for i in l} O(n), or is it O(kn) as my post initially implied? I would expect the later, but haven't looked into the implementation of count.

Comment: @Mark I am not sure, but anyway use `Counter` don't really use the other

Comment: @Mark it is not linear, as you search the entire list each time for each element

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
l = ["apple", "orange", "orange", "apple", "grape"]
print(dict(Counter(l)))
```

This outputs:

```
{'apple': 2, 'orange': 2, 'grape': 1}
```