# How to count an element in a list inside a list in Python

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have a list like this:

```
[(9600002, 42, 3),
(9600001, 17, 3),
(9600003, 11, 1),
(9600002, 14, 5),
(9600001, 17, 1),
(9600003, 11, 4),
(9600001, 17, 4),
(9600001, 14, 3),
(9600002, 42, 6),
(9600002, 42, 1)]
```

The first number is the ***user_id***, the second is the ***tv_program_code***, and the third is the ***season_id***.

### My question

How can I find out the **program_code** with more than ***1 season*** subscribed, and then print the **user_id** and the **tv_program_code**?  For example:

```
9600001 17
```

Or do you have any suggestion of which data structure I should apply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to use `collections.Counter`.

The idea is to count the number of series per (user, program) combination using a dictionary.

Then filter for count greater than 1 via a dictionary comprehension.

```
from collections import Counter

lst = [(9600002, 42, 3), (9600001, 17, 3), (9600003, 11, 1),
       (9600002, 14, 5), (9600001, 17, 1), (9600003, 11, 4),
       (9600001, 17, 4), (9600001, 14, 3), (9600002, 42, 6),
       (9600002, 42, 1)] 

c = Counter()

for user, program, season in lst:
    c[(user, program)] += 1

print(c)

# Counter({(9600002, 42): 3, (9600001, 17): 3, (9600003, 11): 2,
#          (9600002, 14): 1, (9600001, 14): 1})

res = {k: v for k, v in c.items() if v > 1}

print(res)

# {(9600002, 42): 3, (9600001, 17): 3, (9600003, 11): 2}

print(res.keys())

# dict_keys([(9600002, 42), (9600001, 17), (9600003, 11)])
```

---

**Note on Counter versus defaultdict(int)**

`Counter` is twice as slow as `defaultdict(int)`, see benchmarking below. You can switch easily to `defaultdict(int)` if performance matters and none of these features are relevant to you:

1. Missing `Counter` keys [don't get added automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19883180/9209546) when querying.
2. You can add / subtract `Counter` objects.
3. `Counter` offers [additional methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), e.g. `elements`, `most_common`.

Benchmarking on Python 3.6.2.

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

lst = lst * 100000

def counter(lst):
    c = Counter()
    for user, program, season in lst:
        c[(user, program)] += 1
    return c

def dd(lst):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for user, program, season in lst:
        d[(user, program)] += 1
    return d

%timeit counter(lst)  # 900 ms
%timeit dd(lst)       # 450 ms
```

Comment: This looks good, but you aren't actually using the `Counter` interface at all, really. Might as well be a defaultdict.

Comment: @miradulo, I have this discussion every time :). I don't see why one should, by default, prefer `defaultdict(int)` over `Counter`. Can you please explain further? [Relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19883015/python-collections-counter-vs-defaultdictint)

Comment: Thx,bro,and there is only one thing i don't understand
res = {k: v for k, v in c.items() if v > 1} 
k: v for k     what is the k doing here?

Comment: `c.items()` iterates through keys and values of your `Counter` dictionary. `k` is the tuple key (i.e. combination of user and program), while `v` is the count. You don't want to modify or filter by the key in this case.

Comment: @jpp The defaultdict class is written in C, whereas a `collections.Counter` is written in Python. But beyond that, just on principle, why use a class giving you a far larger interface that you don't actually need?

Comment: @miradulo, In general, counting tasks are *often* (but not always) linked with using the other functionality available to `Counter`. You can add 2 Counters (e.g. `c1+c2`), you can use `c.most_common()`, you don't add new keys when you query for them. However, the performance issue is definitely a good point. If it's significant, it should be included as an answer to [Python: Collections.Counter vs defaultdict(int)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19883015/python-collections-counter-vs-defaultdictint).

Comment: @jpp That's not really a compelling counterargument. You have a specific question here that doesn't need this interface, however useful it may be in other circumstances.

Comment: Also, not to nag, but your benchmark will be WAY closer if you use a more Counter-like way to create a Counter. Like `c = Counter((user, program) for user, program, _ in lst)`. That's really my gripe with your answer, you're using a Counter like a defaultdict.

Comment: @miradulo, Fair point on loop syntax. I think it's entirely reasonable to expect users to query a counter (e.g. `d[(user, program)]`), and entirely reasonable to expect a key is *not* added as a result. One's faster, another has additional functionality. But *both* make *non-trivial* assumptions.

Comment: Based on the actual question at hand, I am not the one making the additional assumptions here :) but I see your point.

Comment: @jpp, one more thing, every sublist belongs to another class, so every sublist is an object when i try these methods i always end up getting the error [ object is not iterable ] , how can i fix this problem?

Comment: @ShaneFAN, I'm afraid I don't know what you mean. I suggest you ask as a question if you're still stuck and I'm sure I or others can look into it.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this task

> first using detaultdict :

```
import collections
data=[(9600002, 42, 3),
(9600001, 17, 3),
(9600003, 11, 1),
(9600002, 14, 5),
(9600001, 17, 1),
(9600003, 11, 4),
(9600001, 17, 4),
(9600001, 14, 3),
(9600002, 42, 6),
(9600002, 42, 1)]

d=collections.defaultdict(list)

for i in data:
    d[(i[0],i[1])].append(i)

print(list(filter(lambda x:len(x)>1,d.values())))
```

output:

```
[[(9600003, 11, 1), (9600003, 11, 4)], [(9600001, 17, 3), (9600001, 17, 1), (9600001, 17, 4)], [(9600002, 42, 3), (9600002, 42, 6), (9600002, 42, 1)]]
```

> Second using itertools groupby :

```
import itertools

print(list(filter(lambda x:len(x)>1,[list(j) for i,j in itertools.groupby(sorted(data),key=lambda x:(x[0],x[1]))])))
```

output:

```
[[(9600001, 17, 1), (9600001, 17, 3), (9600001, 17, 4)], [(9600002, 42, 1), (9600002, 42, 3), (9600002, 42, 6)], [(9600003, 11, 1), (9600003, 11, 4)]]
```

> Third approach

At last you can also try manual approach instead of using any import :

```
d={}

for i in data:
    if (i[0],i[1]) not in d:
        d[(i[0],i[1])]=[i]
    else:
        d[(i[0],i[1])].append(i)

print(list(filter(lambda x:len(x)>1,d.values())))
```

output:

```
[[(9600003, 11, 1), (9600003, 11, 4)], [(9600001, 17, 3), (9600001, 17, 1), (9600001, 17, 4)], [(9600002, 42, 3), (9600002, 42, 6), (9600002, 42, 1)]]
```

Comment: Ayodhyankit Paul, one more thing, every sublist belongs to another class, so every sublist is an object when i try these methods i always end up getting the error [ object is not iterable ] , how can i fix this problem?

Comment: @ShaneFAN show me example , I am not able to get your issue.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49720361/object-is-not-iterable-in-python?noredirect=1#comment86453979_49720361)@Ayodhyankit Paul