# How to use defaultdict in dict.fromkeys?

Tags: python

I want to count the histogram for a property value(depth here) of 3 different samples with 1 dictionary.

```py
SamplesList = ('Sa','Sb','Sc')
from collections import defaultdict
DepthCnt = dict.fromkeys(SamplesList, defaultdict(int))
```

This code will make DepthCnt contains 3 `defaultdict(int)` of the same one, thus I cannot count different samples.

How can I do it right ?

It is OK to use either `DepthCnt[sample][depth]` or `DepthCnt[depth][sample]`.

---

I tested these 3 ways:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
DepthCnt = {key:defaultdict(int) for key in SamplesList}
yDepthCnt = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))

from collections import Counter
cDepthCnt = {key:Counter() for key in SamplesList}
```

The memory size are:

```
 DepthCnt[sample][depth]:  993487
yDepthCnt[depth][sample]: 1953307
cDepthCnt[sample][depth]:  994207
```

It seems good to change to `Counter()`.

Comment: Your question is not clear as to what you wish to accomplish. What is the result that you want?

Comment: If you're counting things, consider using `collections.Counter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to count occurences of `sammples` in `SamplesList`. If so you're looking for a [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects)

**Given:**

```
SamplesList = ('Sa','Sb','Sc')
```

**Counter:**

```
from collections import Counter
DepthCnt = Counter(SamplesList)
print(DepthCnt)
#Counter({'Sc': 1, 'Sa': 1, 'Sb': 1})
```

**Edit:**

You can always use a counter instead of a defaultdict as well

```
DepthCnt = {key:Counter() for key in SamplesList}
print(DepthCnt)
#DepthCnt = {'Sa': Counter(), 'Sb': Counter(), 'Sc': Counter()}
```

**P.S**

If you're working over a large dataset as well take a look into the Counter class both Counter and defaultdict are similar below is the TLDR from [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19883180/225020) to a question on [`Collections.Counter` vs `defaultdict(int)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19883015/python-collections-counter-vs-defaultdictint)

> - Counter supports most of the operations you can do on a multiset. So,
>     if you want to use those operation then go for Counter.
> - Counter won't add new keys to the dict when you query for missing
>     keys. So, if your queries include keys that may not be present in the
>     dict then better use Counter.
> - Counter also has a method called most_common that allows you to sort items by their count. To get the same thing in defaultdict you'll have to use sorted.

Comment: I need `DepthCnt['Sa']` and `DepthCnt['Sb']` point to different dict.

Comment: About `Counter`, will it store all items in memory, or just store a histogram ? I have a huge file to count.

Comment: Counter will hold one value for every duplicate item in memory, and the number of occurences for each item

Comment: DepthCnt['Sa'][int(1)] +=1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Comment: How can I add/append to the counter ?

Comment: See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects) They will show you everything you need. There's more than one way

Comment: They show how to init a Counter with a list in memory. But I need to append items one at a time. There is no examples for `Counter.update`.

Comment: Your original code is fine, You need to init the counter, that's my fault it should be `Counter()` not `Counter` - *I edited.* Just use `DepthCnt['Sa'][1] +=1` like you were before

Answer (score 4):

Use a [dictionary expression/comprehension/display](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries)

```
DepthCnt = {key:defaultdict(int) for key in SamplesList}
```